# Task is to create a code in O(n log n), what is the time complexity of this code that I wrote?

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity, big-o

I'm learning big O and time complexity and I find it hard to understand. Can you help me understand the time complexity for this code that I wrote?

Basically the task is to go through an array of numbers and count the number of pairs that satisfies `arr[i] > arr[j]`. Like for the array given in this code `arr = {7, 3, 8, 1, 5}`, the pairs found should be `(7, 3),(7, 1),(7, 5),(3, 1),(8, 1),(8, 5)` and the total number of pairs is `6`.

The task is to create the code with time complexity of O(n log n) but big O still confuses me. I'm not sure if this is O(n^2) and not sure if the program will slow down with bigger arrays.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {7, 3, 8, 1, 5};
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The number of pairs is " + countPair(arr));
    }
    public static int countPair(int[] arr) {
        int i = 0, j = 1;
        int ctr = 0;
        int len = arr.length;
        while (i < len) {
            if (j == len) {
                i++;
                j = 1;
            }
            else if (i < j && (arr[i] > arr[j])) {
                ctr++; // Counting pairs
            }
            j++;
        }
        return ctr;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The number of pairs is 6
```

Comment: What's your algorithm? Separate code from design and you can understand Big O .

Comment: you have `O(n^2)` complexity, simply count the number of times, the program executes in your code : it's 5,4,3,2,1 , or n , n -1 , n-2 .... 1 -> which can be simplified to n*(n-1) which means O(n^2)

Comment: not giving the final solution, as you should figure this out yourself, best of luck 

Comment: Any tips on where I should focus at to get to O(n log n)?

Comment: your while loop logic 